# display custom twodimensional array in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, multidimensional-array

i want to display this two-dimensional array of buttons with 3 buttons in one line, 5 on the next line and 3 buttons on the last line, but they all come out on a single line - what am I doing wrong?

```
public class GUICustombuttonstwodimarray extends JFrame {
    static final String title = "Custom Buttons";
    int row, col;
    JPanel panel;

    JButton[][] jbut = { { new JButton("0"), new JButton("1"), new JButton("2") },
        { new JButton("3"), new JButton("4"), new JButton("5"), new JButton("6"), new JButton("7") },
        { new JButton("8"), new JButton("9") }, { new JButton("10") }
    };

    public GUICustombuttonstwodimarray(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);

        panel = new JPanel();

        for (row = 0; row < jbut.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < jbut[row].length; col++) {
                panel.add(jbut[row][col]);
            }
        }
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUICustombuttonstwodimarray g = new GUICustombuttonstwodimarray(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html, especially GridBagLayout might be interesting.

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: This tutorialspoint article gives an example which is very similar to what you're trying to achieve: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awt/awt_gridlayout.htm

Comment: @AkshayDamle Unless you're going to add "filler" components, `GridLayout` might not be the best choice available

Answer (score 2):

There might be a few ways to achieve, but the simplest might be just to just use a `GridBagLayout`, for example

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GUICustombuttonstwodimarray extends JPanel {

    static final String TITLE = "Custom Buttons";
    int row, col;

    JButton[][] jbut = {{new JButton("0"), new JButton("1"), new JButton("2")},
    {new JButton("3"), new JButton("4"), new JButton("5"), new JButton("6"), new JButton("7")},
    {new JButton("8"), new JButton("9")}, {new JButton("10")}

    };

    public GUICustombuttonstwodimarray() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        for (row = 0; row < jbut.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < jbut[row].length; col++) {
                add(jbut[row][col], gbc);

                gbc.gridx++;
                if (gbc.gridy == 0 && gbc.gridx >= 3) {
                    gbc.gridy++;
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                } else if (gbc.gridy == 1 && gbc.gridx >= 5) {
                    gbc.gridy++;
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GUICustombuttonstwodimarray());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more details